# How to list suspended apps?

Tags: command-line, disable-app

You can "suspend" user apps via `cmd package suspend <packageName>` (which acts kind of like `pm disable`; the differences are explained in [this answer](/a/208271/16575) by @Firelord), and later unsuspend them using `cmd package unsuspend <packageName>` – which also works for user-installed apps. However: suspended packages seem no longer to be listed via `cmd package list packages` – not even if `-u` (uninstalled) or `-d` (disabled) is specified; not even `dumpsys package` seems to know them anymore.

So is there any way to obtain a list of suspended packages? The syntax output doesn't mention such. But as such apps are still shown in the launcher (though "grayed out"), there must be a way to detect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly good with  bash scripts so I'm posting a bit of an ugly one-liner which prints the packages which are currently suspended. Tested on Android 11 and 12 (both Android Emulator).

**Works without root access**:

```
adb shell
pm list packages -a | sed -e 's/^package://'| while read package; do status="$(dumpsys package $package | grep -o "suspended=true")"; if [[ "$status" == "suspended=true" ]] then echo "$package"; fi; done
```

What we are doing in simpler terms is get package names of all the installed apps; then for each package dump its content using `dumpsys package`, and within each dump check for the string which *et al* mentions this substring `suspended=true`. If found, we print the package name, otherwise, we skip to the next package name and repeat the process.

**If you have root access (won't work on Android 12)**:

```
adb shell
su
grep 'suspended="true"' /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml | cut -d '"' -f2
```

This is very fast compared to non-root solution. Also prints names of packages which are currently suspended.

Comment: Thanks – but the first command again does not show the suspended packages (also not if replaced by the corresponding newer `cmd` command – both yield "unknown option -a"). The second one did the trick after a slight modification: I had to ommit the `="true"` for some reason I don't get. But `adb shell su -c grep 'suspended' /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml | cut -d '"' -f2` indeed did the trick, thanks!

Comment: PS: moving the `grep` back to the PC also works: `adb shell su -c cat /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml |grep 'suspended="true"'| cut -d '"' -f2`